# Notification Center does not show app on some devices

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have release an app on the app store with push notifications enabled and have also tested this in a live state to make sure that they are in fact working. The problem comes in when I have certain users stating that the application does not show up in the notification center. The majority of users do not have an issue with this and as soon as the app is installed it asks "do you want to receive push notifications" but there are some that never receive this message. I have the correct methods implemented as this does work for most everyone. Has anyone come across this issue and is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that there were 50 views on this and I did open a case with Apple since I did not get a response. The result was an email stating that I did not have an aps-environment entitlement. This does not make sense since I have several phones that show they are enabled for push....

However, This is the solution to my issue.

```
    
I'm responding to your question about your app not receiving push notifications 
after being released on the App Store.

The first thing I'd check is the code signing entitlements of your app. Since 
your app is free, I downloaded a copy and checked its code signing entitlements
as discussed in the section "Error Delegate Callback" of Technical Note TN2265
"Troubleshooting Push Notifications":

developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-SUBSECTION2.

$ codesign -d --entitlements - /Users/me/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Mobile\ Applications/some.app 
Executable=/Users/me/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications/some.app
??qq?


plist version="1.0">
dict>
    key>application-identifier /key>
    string>12346789.com.XXXX.XXXX /string>
    key>keychain-access-groups /key>
    array>
        string>123465789.com.XXXXXXX.XXXXX /string>
    /array>
/dict>
/plist>

Note that there is no aps-environment entitlement, which is required in order to register for push notifications. ...
```